# Can I load an existing UIview on the storyboard into a UIScrollview?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, ios8, autolayout

I have a design that I have fully laid out with constraints and I now need that view in a UIScrollview. When I go to do an embed in scrollview all the constraints are gone. Is there a way I can load that storyboard view into a UIscrollview programatically?

Comment: Why you want to add a UIView to your UIScrollView? A better way is to make your UIScrollView be the subview of your UIView. You can do `myView.addSubview(myScrollView)`, and set the frame of your UIScrollView equals to your UIView's frame.

Comment: Can we see 1) The code you're using to embed the view in the scrollview, starting from the place you get it off the storyboard, and 2) A screenshot of the View in IB?